# HTML5: accessing large structured local data

Tags: html, local-storage, filereader, opendatabase

**Summary:**
Are there good HTML5/javascript options for selectively reading chunks of data (let's say to be eventually converted to JSON) from a large local file?

**Problem I am trying to solve:**
Some existing program locally and outputs a ton of data. I want to provide a browser-based interactive viewer that will allow folks to browse through these results. I have control over how the data is written out. I can write it all out in one big file, but since it's quite large, I  can't just read the whole thing in memory. Hence, I am looking for some kind of indexed or db-like access to this from my webapp.

**Thoughts on solutions:**
1. Brute-force: HTML5 FileReader API has a nice slice() method for random access. So I could write out some kind of an index in the beginning of the file, use it to look up positions of other stored objects, and read them whenever they're needed. I figured I'd ask if there are already javascript libraries that do something like this (or better) before trying to implement this ugly thing.
2. HTML5 local database. Essentially, I am looking for an analog of HTML5 openDatabase() call that would open (a read-only) connection to a database based on a user-specified local file. From what I understand, there's no way to specify a file with a pre-loaded database. Furthermore, even if there was such a hack, it's not clear whether the local file format would be the same across browsers. I've seen the phonegap solution that populates the browser local database from SQL statements. I can do that too, but the data I am talking about is quite large (5-10GB): it will take a while to load, and such duplication seems rather pointless.

Comment: is it an option to split the file on the local file system into manageable chunks ?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 does not sound like the appropriate answer for your needs.  HTML5's focus is on the client side, and based on your description you're asking a lot out of the browsers, most likely more than they can handle.

I would instead recommend you look at a server-based solution to deliver the desired goal/results to the client view, something like Splunk would be a good product to consider.